# c compare char with argv keep getting comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c

hi all so i've been spending hours on this. Ik it's a simple fix but I can't find it
comparison between pointer and integer. I am getting an arguement from user input that is only a character long. Trying to compare it to this character
main is in a variable

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   char line [10][10];
   line [1] = "t.a";
```

I tried two things
first

```
if(line[1][1] == argv[1])
```

but I got warning: comparison between pointer and integer
second

```
   if(strcmp(argv[1],line[1][1]) == 0)
```

but i got

note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)

I tried both cases with single quotes and double quotes

I am trying to compare two character one character is from argv[1] which should be only 1 single character like "A" and line[1][1] which should be a single character like '.'

Comment: `strcmp(argv[1], ".")`... `strcmp()` takes C strings, not a string and a character.

Comment: `argv` is an array of *strings*.

Comment: thanks sorry I modify it a bit it was alreadyif(strcmp(argv[1], line[1][1]) == 0) that was giving me the error note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’ extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2) when line[1][1] is a character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new information, you should be comparing the string in `argv[1]` with the string in `line[1]`:

```
strcmp(argv[1], line[1])
```

Assuming that `line[1]` is an actual null-terminated string.`

---

Also note that

```
line [1] = "t.a";
```

will not work, as `line[1]` is an array and you can't initialize an array. You can however *copy* to an array:

```
strcpy(line[1], "t.a");
```

Or initialize the array:

```
char line[10][10] = {
    "",
    "t.a"
    // If not explicitly initialized, the remaining elements will be "zero" initialized
};
```

---

It seems you really want to compare *characters* and not strings. So then *compare* characters:

```
if (argc > 1 && strlen(argv[1]) == 1 && argv[1][0] == line[1][0])
{
    // argv[1] is valid, contains a single character,
    // and that character is equal to line[1][0]
    // Do whatever is needed here..
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help once I copy strcpy(line[1], "t.a") how would I compare line[1][1] to argv[1]?

Comment: @dragonn So you really want to compare *characters*? Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks this is what I was lookin for. thanks again for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

SO the problem is that argv is a vector of pointers and when you try to compare a string that the user write you have to make "if('.' == *argv[1])" the pointer of argv[1] for you can acsess to the characters of string! Beacause what you are trying to do is compare the adress of the first element of argv[1].

Comment: thanks sorry I modify it a bit it was alreadyif(strcmp(argv[1], line[1][1]) == 0) that was giving me the error note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’ extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2) when line[1][1] is a character

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is wrong because in C you don't use "==" to compare strings.  You must use [strcmp()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html): `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);`.

You seem to understand this - you used "strcmp()" in your second example.

But strcmp() (per the documentation in my link above), compares *strings*: null-terminated character arrays.  You're comparing a string (`argv[1]`) with a char (`'.'`).  Hence the compiler warning.

This would work: `if(strcmp(argv[1],'.') == 0) { ... }`.

Note that a single quotes (') means a [character literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal); double quotes (") is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Comment: thanks sorry I modify it a bit it was alreadyif(strcmp(argv[1], line[1][1]) == 0) that was giving me the error note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’ extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2) when line[1][1] is a character

Comment: You changed your post and added "line" after my response.  Nevertheless: it's the same problem.  You defined line: `char line[10][10];`.  VALID: `strcmp(argv[1], line[1])`, because "line[1]" is an array.   INVALID: `strcmp(argv[1],line[1][1])`, because line[1][1] is a *char*.  line[10][10]: a 2-d array of characters.  line[0]: the first element of "line", an array of characters.  line[0][0]: the first element of "line", a character.  Look here: https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/2d-arrays-in-c-example/

Comment: thankyou. so how would I compare it to make it valid? (I'm trying to compare the two char one from line[1][1] and argv[1]

Comment: What you claim "should work" doesn't since you use single character literal instead of a string.